# what to get content which div first class name using php preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

i want parse using regular expression

`Option1` suppose div **class ="class1 class2 class3 class4"**

My HTML like this

```
<div class="calss1 class2 class3">
    Content 1
</div>
<div class="calss1 class2 class3">
    Content 2
</div>
<div class="calss1 class2 class3">
    Content 3
</div>
<div class="calss1 class2 class3">
    Content 4
</div>
<div class="calss1 class2 class3">
    Content 5
</div>
```

i want to get all div content using first portion of div class name
   i have try this
    where **$my_content** is total page contnet

```
 if (preg_match('/<div class="class1">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $my_content, $img)) {
            echo 'working';
        }
```

it is working when content like this

```
<div class="calss1">
    Content 1
</div>
```

i need to check only first class name not full class name using regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/<div class="class1(\s.*?)?">(.*?)<\/div>/is';
```